# How to make sure that content never scrolls under a fixed material toolbar?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

The below demo as a material toolbar that is styled like this:

```
mat-toolbar {
    display:flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

### Full screen

https://angular-material-toolbar-fixed-with-styling.stackblitz.io/

### Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar-fixed-with-styling?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How should we keep the lorem ipsum text from scrolling under the fixed toolbar?

I tried wrapping the `router-outlet` in a div and putting a `margin-top: 2rem` on the div, but this moves the toolbar down as can be seen in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below style from

```
.RouterOutlet {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

to

```
.RouterOutlet {
  padding-top: 4rem; /* since mat-toolbar taking height of 64px. (1rem = 16px) */
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .RouterOutlet {
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - It's a great start - Thanks!  When the screen size is smaller the text still scrolls under the toolbar, all though not initially.  Is it possible to have the text never scroll under the toolbar?  In other words it's almost as if the start of the top of the viewport moves below the toolbar?

Comment: I'm guessing we have to put it inside a `div` that is scrollable in the Y direction and that Div should stay fixed under the toolbar ... just a rough idea ...

Comment: Written a media query for smaller size. (mat-toolbar is taking height of 56px at media query point 599px)